# Python regex matching multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get the contents of a `<ul>` tag from a webpage in python. I used the following code:
    `matchResult = re.search(r'<ul\s*content="MSL">(.*)</ul>', queryResult, re.MULTILINE)`
This does not work.
However if I remove the line breaks by using 
`queryResult = queryResult.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')`
It works.

This regular expression in PHP works fine without removing line breaks:
`preg_match('@<ul\s*content="MSL">(.*)</ul>@msU', $queryResult, $matches);`

How can I match over multiple lines using Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the `re.DOTALL` option as well, that will allow the `.` character to match newlines.