# Write regex for a text with several \n

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

This regex `<li>.*end` does not work for the following text, what I'm doing wrong?

text

```
    <li>asdsadasd
adssadasdasdasdas
asdasdasdasdasdad
adsasdasdasdasd
dasdadadsadadasdasdasdasda
end
```

Can someone help me write a regex to grab all the text?

Comment: A similar question was asked here before http://stackoverflow.com/q/7173171/1328439. Note the .DOTALL option used in the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `.` does not match newlines.  You must pass the `DOTALL` flag...

```
regex = re.compile('<li>.*end', re.DOTALL)
```

Or equivalently,

```
regex = re.compile('<li>.*end(?S)')
```

**Edit:** Not the `re.MULTILINE` flag -- that changes the behavior of `$` and `^`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to select multiline option from `re`:

```
import re
expr = re.comile("<li>.*end", re.M)
```

Considering the comments and Dietrich's answer, if you need the behaviour of `$` and `^` to be the same, use `re.DOTALL` instead of `re.M/re.MULTILINE`.

Comment: You want DOTALL mode (`re.S`), not MULTILINE. See [Dietrich's (updated) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14417309/20938)

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing it out; I've added this info to the answer.